# Chrome live caption not working on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: google-chrome, video, 21.04

Live caption feature in Chrome is not working for me. I have Chrome 91.0.4472.114 and
Ubuntu 21.04 64-bit

I can't find anything about this problem on the internet. Is this a known issue?

(The feature I m talking about: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10538231?hl=en)

Comment: It didn't work for me on Chromium, but it worked on Google Chrome

Comment: @WiseTap are u sure it's Chrome v 91+?

Comment: My Google Chrome version is 92.0.4515.107